# Set the color of a dataset label in Chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

I have a bar chart where I want to change the color of the dataset label, to indicate wether the values is problematic or not. Is that possible? And how?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

(Clarification)

As you can see from this screenshot, the font color of the **dataset labels** ("Berners-Lee, T", "Boe, J", etc) is black. I want to be able to modify the color of dataset labels individually. Specifically, I want the label of the third dataset ("Columbus, C") to have a red font.

[image: chart]

Comment: Can you give more information and an example?

Comment: Hey @Matt, see my updated question